# BibTeX/BibLaTeX Citation Formatting Utilities

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex

I have a huge list of URL references. It's just URLs and nothing else, in csv or one-per-line format. Is there some kind of tool or utility I can use to iterate through this list to retrieve the title of the page and format it for BibTeX? Or something similar?

I could put together a script myself, but I don't have time to re-invent the wheel on this if there's something already available. It's not the first time I've needed a little helper for BibTeX references, so I assume I'm not the only one.

Something like [CiteThisForMe](http://www.citethisforme.com/bibtex/source-type) would be ideal if it could take a list as input.

Comment: I'd use a Python script with BeautifulSoup to a) visit each URL and b) extract the content of the title tag. But I am not aware of a software that does this (I might write on during the weekend)

Comment: Related tool (generates `.bib` entry from DOI): https://github.com/foucault/citation, (same, but also mentions URLs): https://github.com/johannesgerer/doi

Comment: I removed the `biblatex` tag since this question is not specifically about the package `biblatex` and its functions, but rather more generally about generating `.bib` files. (*edit* I see you rolled back the edit. Any particular reason for that?)

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen I've provided a bit of a prototype below. You're welcome to do as you please with it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something I whipped up.
It's not going to win any style awards, but it's sufficient for the task at hand.
You're welcome to use, modify, distribute, whatever.
At the very least it should save you some time if you're writing your own.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import requests,urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

titles = []
count  = 0
with open(sys.argv[-1]) as f:
  urls = list(f)

urllib3.disable_warnings()
try:
  for url in urls:
    try:
      html = requests.get(url=url,verify=False)
      if html.status_code in (400,404):
        raise requests.exceptions.InvalidURL()
    except (requests.exceptions.InvalidURL):
      continue
    except (requests.exceptions.ConnectionError):
      continue

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text,'lxml')
    try:  
      title = soup.find('title').string
      titles.append(title)
      print('@misc{'+str(count)+',')
      print('    url   = '+url,end='')
      print('    title = '+title,end='\n}\n')
      count += 1
    except (AttributeError):
      continue 
except (KeyboardInterrupt):
  print(); exit()
```